# доступ с одного контейнера к другому по доменному имени

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Что есть:

docker-compose конфиг

```
    version: '2'
    services:
       web:
         image: nginx
         hostname: site.dev
         links:
           - app
         ports:
           - "80:80"
       app:
         image: php
         volumes:
           - /var/www:/var/www
```

### Проблема:

запускаю `docker-composer run app curl -v site.dev` и получаю ошибку
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to site.dev port 80: Connection refused`. Если запустить `docker-composer run app curl -v web` то все отлично

### Вопрос:

как контейнеру "app" сообщить что контейнер "web" имет доменное имя site.dev?

### Дополнение:

- добавить для контейнера app `links web:site.dev` невозможно, так как
  ругаеться на круговую зависимость
- добавить extra_hosts вида `site.dev:172.17.0.2` можно, но придеться каждый раз подправлять ip адрес
- создать билдер где будет добавляться в /etc/hosts `172.17.0.2 site.dev` можно, но проблема будет таже что и в примере выше

Comment: добавьте dnsmasq отдельным контейнером, самое популярное изображение весит мегабайт восемь. Придется, впрочем, покурить документацию по командной строке, по-моему, будет нужен ключ -A (и, возможно, будет необходимо баш-скриптом выцепить конкретный айпи)

Comment: @Etki  
дело в том что есть docker-proxy и docker network, и я догадываюсь что сам докер умеет разруливать эти проблемы, но пролистав доку я не понял как. – duhon 3 часа назад

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можно убрать links c контейнера web и добавить в app с алиасом домена. Таким образом можно избежать круговую зависимость. Инструкция hostname никак не влияет на внешние контейнеры, это всиголиш внутрее имя контейнера проявляеться только если зайти в bash

```
version: '2'
    services:
       web:
         image: nginx
         ports:
           - "80:80"
       app:
         image: php
         links:
           - web:site.dev
         volumes:
           - /var/www:/var/www
```

если нужно сделать links c двух сторон, тоесть

```
version: '2'
    services:
       web:
         image: nginx
         ports:
           - "80:80"
         links:
           - app:site2.dev
       app:
         image: php
         links:
           - web:site.dev
         volumes:
           - /var/www:/var/www
```

возникнет ошибка `ERROR: Circular dependency between web and app`, пока что ее решить можно опцией extra_hosts